# Count the number of "e"s in a string without using the letter "e"

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source

Your code may not contain the letter "e", but must count the number of "e"s in the inputted string and output that as a number. Bonus points if you use a language that is not a codegolf language and a language that actually uses the letter e (unlike brainfuck) --- not a required criteria.

Comment: Case sensitive, I assume?

Comment: Up to your discretion

Comment: Is it okay if output is in unary?

Comment: yes @ComradeSparklePony

Comment: _Edit: New challenge! Don't use the characters "101"_ Please don't arbitrarily change the rules once answers have been posted. For future challenges I advise you to use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before posting here

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 4 bytes

Nope, definitely didn't use `e`!

```
è'Ev
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=6CdFdg==&input=ImVlZWVlZWVlIg==)

---

### Explanation

```
    :Implicit input of string U
è   :Count.
'E  :"E".
v   :Convert to lowercase.
    :Implicit output of result.
```

Comment: Nice. I had this, `èEsG`, `èdcÄ`, and `èfcÉ`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
101=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39DA0Lb4/391j9ScnHyF8vyinBR1AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
#~StringCount~StringDrop[ToString[2<1],4]&
```

input

> ["dfhjkeehjke"]

output

> 3

Comment: You can save a byte by using infix notation: `ToString[2<1]~StringDrop~4` as the second argument to `StringCount`.

Comment: or infix StringCount

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Oċ“d’
```

A monadic link returning the count.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//SPejhjkpjxpm/v//Xyk8NSc5PzdVoSRfIaAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontVhBTcE5PyVVwT0/J01RCQA)**

#### How?

```
Oċ“d’ - Link: list of characters
O     - cast to ordinals
  “d’ - base 250 number 101
 ċ    - count occurrences
```

Alternatives:
`O’ċȷ2` - decrement (`’`) and count occurrences of 100 (`ȷ2`);
`ƓO’ċ³` - evaluate a line from STDIN (`Ɠ`), decrement (`’`) and count occurrences of 100 (`³`)

Comment: It's unfortunate that using an argument instead of STDIN overwrites the `³ == 100` mapping.

Comment: I really like how you used base 250 number 101

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Yes, that and `⁹==256` do bite the count fairly often (pun-intended), and occasionally `⁸==“”`.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 9 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @Adam*

```
≢⍞∩22⊃⎕AV
```

**How?**

```
    22⊃⎕AV  ⍝ 'e'
 ⍞∩         ⍝ intersect with input
≢            ⍝ count
```

Comment: Save two bytes: `≢⍞∩22⊃⎕AV`

Comment: @Adám thanks! can `⊃` always be used for single element indexing?

Comment: For single elements from a vector, yes. [However.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37875672#37875672)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
q'd)f=:+
```

Case sensitive.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v1A9RTPN1kr7/3@P1JycfB2FnNSSktQiBSVXJUUA)

#### Explanation

```
q             Read input string
    f=        For each character in that string, see if it equals
 'd           character "d"
   )          increased by 1 (that is, character "e")
      :+      Sum the results. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## brainf***, 215 bytes

case sensitive

```
+[>>>>+++++[-<++>]<[-<++++++++++>]<[-<<->>]<<-[>-<[-]]>+<,]>[>>+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<+>[<->[>++++++++++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]++++++++[<++++++>-]>[<<+>>-]>[<<+>>-]<<]>]<[->>++++++++[<++++++>-]]<[.[-]<]<
```

155 of the bytes are from printing the number, from [here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck_algorithms#Print_value_of_cell_x_as_number_for_ANY_sized_cell_.28ie_8bit.2C_16bit.2C_etc.29).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xDgJBDAO/QkcRwgsifyRKAejQISSKA96/zC6coMCNnazt7HE5XG7n5@namqWAdaSHmSoGr3jP4UKEp5yxSha7ElFDsS86EmGwV@ckkvr2EBNxDOTGKYSNVsDOa7Xm5zxNvdT0K7q3f0n6Y@dhT1FUtPaYl2naTNv7Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>30</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

Extremely basic:

```
lambda s:s.count('\x65')
```

4 bytes off thanks to @Challenger's suggestion (adapted to this solution).

<s>51</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes, but I like it better:

```
lambda s:''.join('1'for i in s if i=='\x65')
```

Output is in unary. I found it first in the hopes that the other way was impossible; for once I'm annoyed that Python lets me do things the easy way.

5 bytes off thanks to @Challenger.

2 bytes off of each thanks to @xnor.

Attribution for the simple method:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Attribution for the unary one:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450897/python-removing-characters-except-digits-from-string

Comment: You can golf the second solution: `lambda s:''.join('1'for i in s if i==chr(101))`

Comment: @Challenger5 change the `input()` to `s` and that'll work

Comment: You can write `'e'` as `'\x65'`.

Comment: `if i=='\x65'` => `if'\x65'==i`

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
Ic!_
o=ML
d'I`
,dOp
```

We read a character and duplicate it, then push a "d" and increment its value to have an e. We then store the equality with `M`. *Now* we invert the input to get True when we're done, and conditionally jump to the print command at the end. Otherwise, we load our other truth value (whether it was an e), conditionally increment, and jump back to the `O`rigin.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 10 bytes

It's annoying that the operation to count the number of instances, `e=`, contains an `e`.

```
q"&dd<":)~
```

This creates a string `&dd<` , increments every code point to get `'ee=`, and then executes it.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 27 Bytes

```php
<?=count_chars($argn)[101];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6uUkVqUqlCeqpBYlKpkzWVvB5S1Tc4vzSuJT85ILCrWACvTjDY0MIy1/v8fAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```scala
_.count(_=='\u0065')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc2xCsIwEIDhV7mtySJZdLBEcHRwchXKNb3WSLiE5CqC@Oxn3X@@vwVMqHl8UhC4YmSgtxBPDc6lwOeFCebjTWrkxZ8uLOB12IW8spjB@@6@OnfYd1Z7KFsjZjZYl2actbb/qmIqDxxJ4raBXCf6Qz8)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Ƶ0ç¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//2FaDw8sPLfr/PzEpOSU1LT0jNRUA)

```
Ƶ0   # Push 101
  ç  # Convert to a character
   ¢ # Count the occurrences of that character
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 11 bytes

```
T`d-f`_f_
f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JCFFNy0hPi2eKw3ISS0uAQA) `e` is indirectly referred to in the translation by creating a range from `d` to `f`. The `d`s and `f`s are deleted and the `e`s are translated to `f`s (we can't use `d` because that would expand to `0-9`). It then suffices to count the `f`s.

Comment: `[d-f-[df]]` saves one byte.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I had no idea you could do that; I think you should go ahead and post that as your own answer.

Comment: Since the challenge is closed, I can't. But I found a large improvement, `\x65` for just 4 bytes.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Ah of course, use of decimal/hex codes was why the challenge got closed in the first place...